# VBA- partially zoom in to the Designer

Tags: excel, designer, vba

I wanted to change some small controls by selecting and arranging them. they are at the bottom right corner, so when I use the usual zoom in, they go out of sight and became inaccessible from my screen. is there any way I can just zoom into my desired controls or set of controls? Also, I can't resize the designer itself, as I already using its maximum width.

Thanks for any help.

[image: zoom.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the properties, [image], select ScrollBars #3, the Set ScrollHeight and Width to 150% of your form hight and width.

Comment: Worked, thanks. Also, I find out i can resize the width of user form more than what I reached by dragging when typing there a value. Anyway, your way is neater. Thanks